# Хеш от функции, портирование на винду

Tags: c, защита

Есть один код, который берет хеш от тела функции:

```
uint32 hash1 (addr_t addr,int words) {
    uint32 h = *addr;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<words; i++) {
        addr++;
        h ˆ= *addr;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Использование:

```
void important_function () {
    ...
}
int main () {
    int v = hash (important_function,1000);
    if (v != 0x4C49F346) {
        crash the program
    }
    important_function(...)
}
```

Как понимаю, функция hash принимает указатель на функцию и количество машинных слов, которое занимает ее код. В цикле проходим по каждому ворду и набираем хеш-сумму.

Два вопроса:
1) Как узнать, сколько вордов занимает функция?
2) Какой аналог addr_t есть в винде? Код написан под линукс.

И общая задача: какие есть способы получить адрес начала и конца некоторого участка кода на винде? Например, чтобы закриптовать его.

Comment: Что-то я не уверен, что компилятор предоставляет вам такой сервис. На уровне компилятора вы даже не можете быть уверены, что функцию не заинлайнит в вызывающий код. Компилятор вовсе не обязан физически располагать в выходном файле все те функции, которые вы определили. Вам придётся смотреть в сторону конкретного toolchain'а, там обычно есть специфические возможности «плотного» контроля компиляции.

Answer (score 2):

addr_t - это, судя по коду, банальный `uint32_t *`.
Разве что я не совсем верю, что код из примера корректно скомпилируется - должно быть что-то вроде

`int v = hash ((uint32_t *)important_function,1000);`

А размер можно получить руками, прочитав map-файл.
Либо вдумчиво изучать конфигурацию линкера, чтобы он ГАРАНТИРОВАННО клал строго после `important_function()` какую-нибудь другую функцию. И вычислять разницу адресов - это и будет размер.

**UPD** Для линкера GCC надо сделать примерно следующее:

- В скрипте линкера в секцию .text добавить что-то вроде

  ```
  . = ImportantStart
  *(.ImportantSection)
  . = ImportantEnd
  ```
- "секретную" функцию объявить как

  ```
  __attribute__ ((section(".ImportantSection")))
  void ImportantFunction ();
  ```
- добавить переменную с размером секции, в которую линкер положит эту функцию

  ```
  // begin/end объявлены в скрипте линкера, не имеют значения, имеют только адрес!
  extern char ImportantBegin, ImportantEnd; 
  size_t ImportantSize = &ImportantEnd - &ImportantBegin;
  ```
- пользоваться :-)

Да, это всё теория. Под "большой" gcc  я ничего подобного не делал, только под микроконтроллерный. Где и как IDE нагенерит скрипт линкера - честно говоря, никогда не задумывался, "большие" программы с такими извращениями писать не приходилось.

Comment: XOR там просто для простоты, чтобы не морочить голову там, где это еще рано. Так можно было бы и такое хеширование рассмотреть: http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/universalnoe-heshirovanie-po-maksimalnoy-krivoy-tretiego-roda

Comment: Чтобы строго после одной функции располагалась следующая, в GCC используется опция -O0?

Comment: О-ноль - это опция компилятора, а раскидыванием функций занимается линкер.Чуток дописал ответ, чтобы было понятнее, насколько глубоко надо залезать во внутренности линкера.

Comment: А куда копать, чтобы научиться писать хотя бы очень простой парсер объектных и PE-файлов? Кроме знания форматов надо ли хорошо знать машины состояния для написания парсера? Что еще требуется?

Comment: Он уже есть - называется objdump ;-)
Думаю, лучше полностью сформулировать вопрос и задать его отдельно. 
Тем более, я не знаю ответ - готовые бинарники я разбирал только вручную, чтобы убедиться, что туда накомпилировалось именно то, что мне надо. Автоматизацией этого я не занимался.